# How to implicit call the default function of a class

Tags: excel, vba

Import this class:

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "MyMsgBox"
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True

Public Function Show(testo As String) as Boolean
Attribute Show.VB_UserMemId = 0
    msgbox testo
    Show = True
End Function
```

and execute this code in a module:

```
MyMsgBox.Show "hi"
If MyMsgBox("hi") = True Then msgbox "it works"
MyMsgBox "hi"  ' << I get "Compile error: Invalid use of property"
```

Why does the last line give the error?
and what's the shortest alternative that works?

Comment: Try wrapping the "hi" in parenthesis `MyMsgBox("hi")`

Comment: @SmileyFtW: I get the same error even with parenthesis

Comment: [Please don't do that. That only makes your code confusing to understand and use.](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2019/07/15/modern-vba-best-practices-default-members/) Consider instead just creating a module or class and using an explicit `Show` method. Even if you're the only developer writing the code, it's worth it writing clean and readable code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## YOU DON'T WANT TO DO THIS.

Default members are evil, implicit and confusing code. [Rubberduck](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) annotations like `@DefaultMember` help make the hidden attributes more visible, but the API is still a weird, unconventional, non-idiomatic VBA code.

A default member that takes a single parameter should be named `Item`, its parameter being the `Index` of an encapsulated collection - the class itself would be some custom collection class.

Every single other use of a default member boils down to abuse.

See [Modern VBA Best Practices: Default Members](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2019/07/15/modern-vba-best-practices-default-members/) for more info.

---

Now with that cleared up...

Because of the `VB_PredeclaredId = True` attribute, the shortest possible way to invoke the default member is:

```
?MyMsgBox("test")
```

That's because `MyMsgBox` is both the name of the class *and* the name of a global-scope object variable of that class type. Note that if you don't capture the return value, it's an "invalid use of property".... note how VBA is kind of assuming default members are `Property` members.

You get parameter quick-info in the IDE for the default member with `MyMsgBox(`:

[image: parameter quick-info is displayed when the ( opening parenthesis is typed]

Exactly *why* the default member call [works fine off a local instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58771251/1188513) (and not off the default one) is muddy and unclear - presumably VBA is getting confused here, understandably so: this is straight-up language feature abuse.

Comment: Hi Mathieu, thanks for the answer.  Actually the original question was a simplification of my real case that is a progress bar class(?) to be used in all my codes with three functions:   step.initialize, step.show, step.close.  I will write a 'step.show "increment", "looooong comment"' line every few lines in every code I write, therefore I'd like to remove the ".show" to gain typing speed and visual space for the comment. What would you do in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Works for me:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim x As MyMsgBox
    Set x = New MyMsgBox

    x.Show "Hi"
    If x("Hi") Then MsgBox "It works"
    x "Hi"
End Sub
```

Chip Pearson has a good [read](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DefaultMember.aspx) on Default Members.

Comment: Interesting but since the "Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True" we don't need to instantiate the class. Is it possible to make it work without instantiating the class?  unfortunately cPearson only treats default properties, not default subs/functions

Comment: That article does mention that the default can be a sub or function,  near the end. Will have to research further on the first question.